# Asp.net core 3 Unicode slug url segment as a parameter in controller HttpGet action method does't receive any url segment value

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

```
Here is my Setup.cs

app.UseMvc(routes =>
 {
var rewrite = new RewriteOptions()             
                .AddRewrite(@"category/(\d+)/([\p{L}\p{M}\-]+)", "Home/Category?id=$1&name=$2", skipRemainingRules: true).AddRedirectToHttpsPermanent();
              app.UseRewriter(rewrite);
routes.MapRoute(
                   name: "default",
                   template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

});
```

Here is my Controller Method

```
public IActionResult Category(Int32 id, String name, Int32 page = 1)
{


            return Ok(name);
}
```

When I send request with the following url with Unicode characters it does't work. But work with English characters: [https://localhost:15000/category/1/চ](https://localhost:15000/category/1/%E0%A6%9A)াল does't work. But work with https://localhost:15000/category/1/rice

When i use Unicode slug it does not receive any value in "name" variable but English slug work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is solved by using Unicode rang \u0980-\u09FF instead \p{L}\p{M}
>   regular expression at AddRewrite() function.